# Getting Pick list selected value from other Python file

Tags: python, class, oop, variables, picklist

I'm trying to get the value of the dropdown list from another Pyton file in the same project.

[image]

This is my code in input.py file:

```
class Input:

Budget = {'Flexible', 'Variable', 'Fixed'}

def __init__(self):

    root =Tk()
    root.title('Input window V1')
    root.geometry('1300x690')
    root.resizable(False, False)

    frame = Frame(root, width=1000, height=680)
    frame.configure(background="gray28")
    frame.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)

    lbl1 = Label(root, bg="gray28", pady=1, text='Budget:', fg="cyan2" , font=("Helvetica", 20))
    lbl1.place(x=240, y=225)

    var1 = StringVar(root)
    #var1.set("None") # default value (Not in use)
    pl1 = OptionMenu(root, var1, *self.Budget )
    pl1.config(width=20, bg="GREEN", fg="white")
    pl1.place(x=470, y=230)

    button1 = Button(root, text="GO Hybrid !", command=dashboard)
    button1.config(width=25, bg="white")
    button1.place(x=600, y=590)

    root.mainloop()
```

and this is the code in the other file I got and I want to get the selected value of pl1 (getting Budget List selected value).

```
from input import Input

print(Input.Budget)
print (var1.get())
```

It does give me all "Budget" list but bot the selected value. this is the Error:
**NameError: name 'var1' is not defined**
Where I should declare it?

Thanks!

Comment: The question is a little vague and hard to reproduce. Are you trying to get the variable var1 from another file?

Comment: @ObjectJosh Yes because I believe it will give me the selected value from the picklist.

Answer (score 1):

If you’re trying to get var1 from another file, initialize your object first.

```py
a = Input()
print(a.var1)
```

In your `__init__`:
`self.var1 = StringVar(root)`

Comment: I initialize var1 and I did get him in the other python file, but I didn't get the selected value from the picklist. Maybe var1 isn't the user selection? Thanks

Comment: What are you using for your GUI? PyQt5?

Comment: I'm using TKInter.